# Build R package but do not ZIP?

Tags: r, package

I'm building an R package on Windows with the following command:

```
R CMD INSTALL -l C:/path/to/output --build pkg_name
```

This works but I dont want it to do the final step of creating the zip file...is there any way to suppress this?

Answer (score 0):

drop the --build option and it won't create the zip file.